# Does Endgame make sense?

Tags: aesthetics, modernism

I believe that Beckett's Endgame is meant to be the epitome of meaningless literature. Some seem to think that the critical theorist Adorno thinks that art is a meaningless brand that shows itself to be meaningless. Others that, in its structured meaninglessness, Endgame shows that the autonomous self is impossible. I prefer the second reading, because if it is reflexively false then that is a lot more exciting than just a 'brand qua a brand'. Do both claims say more or less the same thing? Is Endgame meaningless or not?

What is the bare minimum of meaning and obligation?

Comment: Some things are impossible.

Comment: some things are not impossible despite contrary claims @AgentSmith

Comment: @zero, you completed the square! Hats off to you.

Comment: it's the best of all worlds alright  @AgentSmith

Comment: ok sorry @MauroALLEGRANZA just an overblown expression about 'meaning'

Comment: i was aware that the so called "existentialist reading" of it existed @MauroALLEGRANZA and it seems fairly straight forward. i wasn't specifically asking about that

Comment: can probably answer my own question, at least to an [extent](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/4946900/mod_resource/content/1/TRYING%20TO%20UNDERSTAND%20ENDGAME%20-%20ADORNO.pdf) and tying in what i asked, if not answering explicitly in what way it has any "meaning"

Answer (score 0):

It seems Adorno praises the play not because of the philosophy Beckett has (which is reduced to "culture-trash"), and not because it captures an existential condition (which would be an immutable reification), but because it is, despite being structured as a parody of drama, meaningless right down to senseless "linguistic molecules", and in this sense its truth content lies in our inescapably meaningless society (and how it reproduces itself through individual antagonism)

> ... he shows as humanly typical only those deformations inflicted on humans by their society... The rudeness and ticks of normal character, which Endgame
> inconceivably intensifies, is that universality of the whole that
> already preforms all classes and individuals; it merely reproduces
> itself through bad particularity, the antagonistic interests of single
> individuals. Because there was no other life other than the false one,
> the catalogue of its defects become the mirror image of ontology.
>
> This shattering into unconnected non-identical elements is nevertheless
> tied to identity in a theatre play...